# How to use LocalDate with Binding

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

My application contains a part where the user inputs their name, email etc. but they can also add the date (it doesn't have an initial value)

The date is a DatePicker.

What I have done is added a binding to a "submit" button to make sure that the users have inputted all the information before the button becomes available, however, I don't know how to bind to the LocalDate.

I tried this method which works (except for the date.getValue() at the end):

```
 public BooleanBinding isEitherFieldEmpty() { //This is for the "SUBMIT binding" to check if all text fields are empty
        return txtFirstName.textProperty().isEmpty().or(txtSurname.textProperty().isEmpty()).or
                (txtPNumber.textProperty().isEmpty()).or(txtEmail.textProperty().isEmpty()).or(date.getValue() == null);
    }
```

the last part: `.or(date.getValue() == null);` gives me an error which says

`The method or(ObservableBooleanValue) in the type BooleanExpression is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)`

I was wondering whether there was another way to bind the button to the LocalDate as well.

Thank you

Comment: `date` is a `DatePicker`?

Comment: @James_D Yes, sorry, I'll clarify that in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `date` is a `DatePicker`, you can just use

```
date.valueProperty().isNull()
```

which returns a `BooleanBinding`. I.e.:

```
public BooleanBinding isEitherFieldEmpty() { //This is for the "SUBMIT binding" to check if all text fields are empty
        return txtFirstName.textProperty().isEmpty()
        .or(txtSurname.textProperty().isEmpty())
        .or(txtPNumber.textProperty().isEmpty())
        .or(txtEmail.textProperty().isEmpty())
        .or(date.valueProperty().isNull());
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much! I looked everywhere online to find an answer. I can accept your answer in 10 minutes :)

Comment: @Yusuf Methods for `ObjectProperty` are scattered over its (many) superclasses and interfaces, but `isNull()` is there in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/beans/property/ObjectProperty.html), inherited from `ObjectExpression`.